# Veracode Cryptography issue

Tags: c#, sha, veracode, cryptographic-hash-function

Recently we done a static security scan using Veracode on one of the applications.

The report indicate an issue

> Use of a Broken or Risky Cryptographic Algorithm (CWE ID 327)

It is shown for following code snippet

```
byte[] CalculateHash(byte[] publicKey) {
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider hashGenerator = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        Byte[] hashInArray = new Byte[32];
        PrivateKey.CopyTo(hashInArray,0);            // Combine public key and private key
        publicKey.CopyTo(hashInArray,16);
        return hashGenerator.ComputeHash(hashInArray); // Calculate hash
    }
```

In description it describe SHA1 as a weak algorithm.

I modified the code and used SHA256 instead of SHA1 and performed veracode scanning again but it still show same issue.

What is an alternative for this? any suggestions?

Comment: Is the reported issue the same?

Comment: @zaph yes same issue

Comment: @zaph hashInArray does get 32-bytes, 16 byte each from private and public key. And then it is passed to ComputeHash.

Comment: OK, perhaps you are attempting to fix the wrong issue.

Comment: Do you mean I am looking at wrong code to fix this issue.... That is issue may be somewhere else???

Comment: Yes, since replacing SHA1 with SHA256 resolves any hash security issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115124/discussion-between-random-thoughts-and-zaph).

Comment: I don't get the copying at all. Any private (or public key for that matter) should be larger than 16 bytes / 128 bits.

Comment: Have you looked into the official following blogpost on SHA for Veracode? https://www.veracode.com/blog/research/message-digests-aka-hashing-functions It looks like there's a lot of nuance to when SHA1 vs SHA256 would be utilized.